# how to use STDIN and STDOUT for input and output in hadoop streaming matlab operation

Tags: matlab, hadoop, stdout, stdin, hadoop-streaming

In matlab operation how to give input and output path for hadoop streaming. I already know that stdin and stdout is default input and output pathway for hadoop streaming. But I am using Matlab code. Here how should i give?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775996/using-standard-io-streamstdin-and-stdout-in-a-matlab-exe

Comment: Yes you are right sir. But those example is exe based. what i want is shell script. Within a shell script i simply called matlab file path like .m  .   My doubt is within a matlab codings how should i give stdin and stdout.